# Why markerSymbol not working in the SkillMetric Taylor Diagram?

Tags: python

I want to change the marker symbol on the Taylor Diagram using skillmetrics in python saying that

```
import skill_metrics as sm
import numpy as np

ss=np.array([34,32,33])
aa=np.array([0,3,2])
cc=np.array([1,.2,.7])
sm.taylor_diagram(ss,aa,cc,markerSymbol='*', titleOBS = 'Ref',colOBS = 'r', markerobs = '*')
```

but it resulting error mentioning as follow

`ValueError: Unrecognized option: markersymbol`

Everything working well if we leave no change the markerSymbol as default, but i need to customize the marker symbol, any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mosc9575 fr enlighten me and I find the answer by updating the repos from here
[Request: Need to be able to change marker shape as well as color on the Taylor diagrams #19](https://github.com/PeterRochford/SkillMetrics/issues/19)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I downloaded this package in version `SkillMetrics-1.1.7`, which is the latest one and I got the same error.

This is because the line [below](https://github.com/PeterRochford/SkillMetrics/blob/8d2bbb2c079ea5673db338c6d78df3c75c830db4/skill_metrics/get_taylor_diagram_options.py#L141), which is included in the github repository, is missing in the latest version.

```
option['markersymbol'] = '.'
```

I added this line using `vi` in my source code

```
vi /opt/conda/envs/development/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skill_metrics/get_taylor_diagram_options.py
```

| before | after |
| --- | --- |
| [image: before] | [image: after] |

and afterwards the code was running.

**Comment**

To be honest, I do not think that this change makes any difference in the output. Please build your own opinion.

| dafault | `markersymbol='*'` |
| --- | --- |
| `sm.taylor_diagram(ss,aa,cc, titleOBS = 'Ref',colOBS = 'r', markerobs='m', markersymbol='.')` | `sm.taylor_diagram(ss,aa,cc, titleOBS = 'Ref',colOBS = 'r', markerobs='m', markersymbol='*')` |
| [image: default] | [image: star] |

Comment: Thank you for your respond, i followed your steps and yes there is no error. However, the symbol we put '*' which should make a star marker is not changing the same marker as 'o'. I tried with other marker such as 'x', 'P', etc but all the output marker is same which is 'o'.  And my actual data consist of 50 differents data from 4 groups which I need to present in different markers not only color.